# ImportError: cannot import name 'Product'

Tags: python, django

Приветствую. Есть две модели: `Product` и `Subscribe`. Эти две модели находятся в разных приложениях.

```
catalog / models / Product
home / models / Subscribe
```

В модели `Subscribe` есть поле:

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images', on_delete='CASCADE')
```

А в модели `Product` поле:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    subscribers = Subscribe.objects.filter(product__id=self.id)
```

При таком видел перекрестных ссылок одной модели на другую и наоборот получаю ошибку:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Product'

Подскажите, как с этим бороться. Мне в первой модели нужен объект второй, а во второй - объект первой. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это результат циклического импорта. Бороться заменой первого параметра `ForeignKey` на строку и убиранием из home.models импорта `from catalog.models import Product`:

```
product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='images', on_delete='CASCADE')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Так и сделал, помогло.